# AngularJS - button - call function or directive before dependency

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, excel

I'm using [`ngJsonExportExcel`](https://github.com/dtagdev1/json-export-excel) dependency to export JSON to EXCEL.

I have an other PHP file that fetch data from sql according to the pushed button, and that data I want to export.

The export happens because of the attributes of the button.
What I want to happen is that when I push the button, it first loads the data, and then exports.

This is the AngularJS:

```
$scope.Export_to_csv = function (odid,hour) {
        $http.get("fetch-sms-list.php?odid="+odid+"&hour="+hour)
           .success(function (data) {
               $scope.smslist=data.result;
            });
    }
```

and this is the button (in a table):

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in records | orderBy: sortType : sortReverse">
                    <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
                    <td>{{row.pname + " " + row.sname}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.areaname}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.oddate}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.odtime}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="Export_to_csv(row.ODid,row.odtime)" ng-json-export-excel data="smslist" report-fields="{'fname': 'Heder 1', 'sname': 'Header 2'}"
                                filename =" 'export-excel' " separator=","
                                class='btn btn-info'>
                            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
```

But as I thought - the export excute first.

Is there a way to solve it? I prefer to avoid multiple buttons even if they hidden.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was seek so I wasn't at work (this code from my work). I saw your answer from home but I couldn't try it. In the end I put another hidden button and pushed it after the data loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a custom directive which adds your `ng-json-export-excel` dynamically and triggers a click -> like in this full runnable **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7qyd29/)**. In this way you dont need a "hidden element".

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="loadData()" 
          data="data" 
          filename="'export-excel'" 
          report-fields="{ body: 'Body' }" 
          loaded="loaded"
          my-directive>
    Load data async
  </button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngJsonExportExcel"]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {

  $scope.loaded = false;
  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.loadData = function() {
    if (!$scope.loaded) {
       $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function (response) { 
          $scope.data = response.data;
          $scope.loaded = true;
       });
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile, $timeout) {
  return {
    restrit: 'A',
    replace: false,
    scope: {
      loaded: "=",
      data: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("loaded", function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
          element.attr('ng-json-export-excel', '');
          element.removeAttr('my-directive');
          $compile(element)(scope);
          $timeout(function() {
            element.triggerHandler('click');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you open the source code of the plugin:

https://github.com/dtagdev1/json-export-excel/blob/master/src/json-export-excel.js

You will see that it acts only as directive/attribute. No services, nothing to call from outside. 
So you have few ways:

1) Change your code in order to add dynamically the directive and compile it after resolved the http request, removing it from the HTML:

```
// note the add of $event
$scope.Export_to_csv = function ($event, odid,hour) {
        alert("fetch-sms-list.php?odid="+odid+"&hour="+hour);
        $http.get("fetch-sms-list.php?odid="+odid+"&hour="+hour)
           .success(function (data) {
               $scope.smslist=data.result;
               $event.currentTarget.attr('ng-json-export-excel', '');
               $compile($event.currentTarget.contents())($scope); // inject $compile
               // inject $timeout to be sure it's called after the compile
               $timeout(function () {
                  $event.currentTarget.triggerHandler('click');
               });
            });
    }
```

2) Create your own directive which wraps this one, adding an attribute for the details of the HTTP request, and performing the HTTP request inside it and then trigger the export

3) **My suggested one:** Create a service in order to do that. If you open the source code of the directive, you have everything that you need. You can also create a PR for that plugin, in order to improve it with a service which does the same without using HTML.
You will allow future users to solve the same problem easily.